# CheckBox isSelected() method always returns false

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I am working on an Android application where I have to check the `CheckBox` selection **onClick()** so I made this

```
                if (checkBoxRM.isSelected() == true) {
                isSelectedValue = "True";
                //debug
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Kiejölés értéke: " + isSelectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //debug
                isSelectedValue = "False";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Kiejölés értéke: " + isSelectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

But seems like **isSelectedValue** is always `false`.

Comment: Don't use onClick, use OnCheckedChangeListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `isSelected()` perform `isChecked()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the checkBox to enable isChecked()

This works:

```
boolean selected = ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.main_cbSelectAll)).isChecked();
```

This not (here, you can only choose "isSelected"):

```
boolean selected = view.findViewById(R.id.main_cbSelectAll).isChecked();
```

If you want to use it as an SQLite-statement, you have to transform to an integer:

```
int selected = ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.main_cbSelectAll)).isChecked() ? 1 : 0;
```